# Convert Debian Jessie to Ubuntu Server 16.04 (without doing a clean install from bootable media)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I would like to convert my debian jessie machine into an ubuntu server machine. Ideally, I just want to swap out all the core packages, preserving my users, files, and other settings. Is this even possible, or am I looking at having to reinstall all the applications I've build on top of this server and create a fresh install of ubuntu server?

My thoughts are something to the effect of swapping out all the packages in sources.list and doing a dist-upgrade or if there is a way to install the commands to do one of ubuntu's release upgrades to try that. Any ideas?

Side note:

You may be wondering why I want to do this. The reason is simple: driver support. I want to do GPU computing on this machine in addition to all its server functions; however, this proved difficult to impossible with companies only releasing newer and well supported drivers for redhat and ubuntu. I don't want to deal with this hassle, so I was looking to just switch the OS.

Comment: You can update Ubuntu from an install disc by forcing it into the same partition as an existing installation. Because the system layouts are similar, it is _possible_ that you may be able to do what you want by installing over the top of the Debian installation, and it might be worth a try, after copious backing up, of course. If you try it and it does work, let us know, because it's an interesting proposition.

Comment: I don't have physical access to this machine until ~the 18th of December, but when I do, I'll give it a go and update my post here. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I'm using proprietary drivers for nVidia GPU here on Debian Stretch. That's GeForce GT 720 (nothing hot, that is) but it works just OK. I mean, maybe just check [this](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/nvidia-driver) and [this](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nvidia&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=non-free) in general) to figure out whether your chip is supported (or not).

Comment: AMD radeon hd 7570 which needs fglrx -driver, and I need opencl to work with it. Fglrx-driver is really broken right now. According to the package page, it's being fazed out.